# How to send POST request using Julia lang HTTP library to a Django RESTFUL API (DRF)

Tags: json, django, django-rest-framework, python-requests, julia

There is very limited documentation when it comes to the HTTP library in Julia Lang. Not just that, but there are no up to date Stack Overflow questions regarding the HTTP library in general.

With that said, how do you send POST requests using Julia + HTTP to a Django Restful API (DRF)?

Answer (score 3):

Julia 1.7, 1.8

If you are sending json formatted data (simple Django POST request):

```
begin

using JSON
using HTTP

const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile"
payload = Dict("email" => "email@email.com", "password" => "12345password")

response = HTTP.request(
        "POST", url, ["Content-Type" => "application/json"], JSON.json(payload))

# this is necessary, JULIA discontinued python style Dictionaries
response = JSON.parse(String(response.body))
println(response)


end
```

If you are sending header information like Authentication tokens, etc.

```
begin

using JSON
using HTTP

const url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/profile"
payload = Dict("email" => "email@email.com", "password" => "12345password")
access_token = "some access token"

headers = Dict(
        "Content-Type" => "application/json",
        "Authorization" => "Bearer $access_token")

response = HTTP.request(
        "POST", url, headers, JSON.json(payload))

# this is necessary, JULIA discontinued python style Dictionaries
response = JSON.parse(String(response.body))
println(response)


end
```

Comment: maybe provide a simple Django service code too so this is a complete example for people learning that sort of thing?

Comment: That sounds like a great idea. I'll try updating this answer in the following days.

Comment: see https://github.com/bkamins/JuliaForDataAnalysis/blob/main/ch14_server.jl (server) and https://github.com/bkamins/JuliaForDataAnalysis/blob/main/ch14.jl (client, look at the last part of the file) for a complete worked example (both client and server are written in Julia). And for GET request example https://github.com/bkamins/JuliaForDataAnalysis/blob/main/ch07.jl